# Output 64 bit integer with hexdump

Tags: c++, binary, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, hexdump

I currently work on some binary data.
In order to check and debug the data previously generated by my application I use *hexdump*, facing the obstacle of hexdump not appearing to be able to extract a 64-bit integer field.
Given the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::ofstream os("tmp.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    uint64_t x = 7;
    os.write((char*)&x,sizeof(uint64_t));
    os.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I perform a simple hexdump on my system:

```
hexdump tmp.bin

> 0000000: 0007 0000 0000 0000
> 0000008:
```

Now trying to extract the unsigned int of 64 bit width yields:

```
hexdump -e '/8 "%u"' tmp.bin

> hexdump: bad byte count for conversion character u
```

According to the well written [hexdump-manual by *David Mair*](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/making-sense-hexdump/) it should be possible to do it, but I have no success.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Unfortunately not as this only modifies the indentation width of the output.

Comment: In the manpages it says only 4bytes are supported most for x and u. Anyway after a little bashing i found this workaround:

hexdump -e '2/4 "%08X" "\n"' FILE | awk '{system("echo \"ibase=16; "$1"\"|bc")}'

It basically prints two 4 byte hex pairs and then converts this to decimal with bc. I don't know if the order of the 2 hex pairs may need to swap for the correct value, but you could give it a try.

Comment: All right, I just tried it out.
The values had to be swapped indeed.
This is how it works:

hexdump -e '2/4 "%08X " "\n"' HEX | awk 'BEGIN{printf "ibase=16; "}{print $2 $1}' | bc

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, now I hit signed numbers. As I don't know if they are represented using a sign bit, one's complement, two's complement, offset binary or negative base representation it will be too much for a quick dump. So our solution will only work on unsigned 64 bit integers.

Comment: I think we can check the most significant bit and if it is set, logical and the number with the mask 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and subtract the result from the mask we should get the signed result i think.

Comment: Well, I found a way to do it with the bash inherent calculator on the awk output. Apparently, bash's $(( )) knows how to transform it correctly.

Comment: @fassl  You may want to put the workaround as an answer:
 `x=\`hexdump -n 8 -e '2/4 "%08X " "\n"' $1 | awk 'BEGIN{printf "0x"}{print $2$1}'\`;
echo $(($x));`

Comment: Ultimately you came up with the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our final workaround reads as follows:

```
x=`hexdump -n 8 -e '2/4 "%08X " "\n"' {FILENAME} | awk 'BEGIN{printf "0x"}{print $2$1}'`
echo $(($x))
```

*Explaination for each part:*

- Extract the eight bytes of the 64-bit integer value from file {FILENAME}
  as two four byte chunks printed as hexadecimal encoded values.

  ```
  hexdump -n 8 -e '2/4 "%08X " "\n"' {FILENAME}
  ```
- Reverses the byte order of the two chunks and prints it as a single eight byte chunk representing the binary value. Prepend *0x* for the following processing.

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{printf "0x"}{print $2$1}
  ```
- Save the hexadecimal representation into x for bash to evaluate.

  ```
  x=`....`
  ```
- Let the bourne shell interpret and output the hexadecimal encoded value of the 64-bit integer variable (here the previously prepended *0x* is needed).

  ```
  echo $(($x))
  ```

Comment: This helps me understand so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: I was able to extend this, which was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

One can use sed also.  The following matches 8 byte hex integers and swaps them.  Again this only works for unsigned integers.

```
hexdump ... | sed 's/0x\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/0x\2\1/'
```

AFAICT one should be able to write much more clearly

```
hexdump ... | sed 's/0x\([0-9a-f]{8,8}\)\([0-9a-f]{8,8}\)/0x\2\1/'
```

typically with some command line option such as -E to enable extended regular expressions, but at least on Mac OS X 10.10 this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the "od" command instead. od -xL outputs long integer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this doesn't work out-of-the-box, but I had the same problem printing 64-bit integers and ended up compiling a better version from `util-linux` found here: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux.  At first I tried installing that package in Ubuntu, but it didn't update `hexdump`, so I decided to try doing it "manually."

It's a bit of work, but not too bad.  Just use `git` to grab the source, run the `autogen.sh` script, and then `./configure` followed by `make hexdump` to compile just that program.  Compiling only took 4 seconds on my laptop.